# conditionally map an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects and I need to introduce the name in a new array where listOfRegistries.Id === listOfTargets.regId

```
  this.listOfRegistries = [
            { id: '123', name: 'name1' },
            { id: '245', name: 'name2' },
           
        ];

this.listOfTargets =  [
            { regId: '123',key: 'value1' },
            { regId: '245', key: 'value2' },
           
        ];
```

I need to achieve this:

```
this. listOfTargetsNew =  [
            { regId: '123',key: 'value1', name: 'name1' },
            { regId: '245', key: 'value2', name: 'name2' },
           
        ];
```

This is what I'm trying with no result

```
this.listOfTargetsNew = this.listOfTargets.map((el, index)=> {
                         if( this.listOfRegistries[index].id === el.regId) {
                             el['name'] = this.listOfRegistries[index].name;
                             return el;
                          }
                         });
```

Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: just be aware that a map cannot change the length of an array

Comment: do you have the same id at the same index in every array?

Comment: This seems extremely fragile/flaky. Can you really assume that the `listOfRegistries` and `listOfTargets` are in the same order and length???!! Surely you'd need to **search** the registries for the marching record, instead of naively only checking the registry at the same array position.

Comment: Just (ignoring the possible order problem) move the `return el` out of the `if` block

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and find the correct name via the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```js
const listOfRegistries = [
  { id: '123', name: 'name1' },
  { id: '245', name: 'name2' },
];

const listOfTargets = [
  { regId: '123',key: 'value1' },
  { regId: '245', key: 'value2' },
];

const listOfTargetsNew = listOfTargets.map((obj) => {
  const registry = listOfRegistries.find(({ id }) => id === obj.regId);
  
  return {...obj, name: registry.name};
});

console.log(listOfTargetsNew);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the registries in an object and map the other array with addtional property.

```js
const
    listOfRegistries = [{ id: '123', name: 'name1' }, { id: '245', name: 'name2' }],
    listOfTargets = [{ regId: '123', key: 'name1' }, { regId: '245', key: 'name2' }],
    registries = Object.fromEntries(listOfRegistries.map(({ id, name }) => [id, name])),
    listOfTargetsNew = listOfTargets.map(o => ({ ...o, name: registries[o.regId] }));

console.log(listOfTargetsNew);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think this is the most efficient answer and it has only two iterations.